# Is it possible for a global attention pooling layer to have "channels"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, pooling

I'm trying to implement a neural model described in a paper, and I've encountered the following sentences:

> Due to smaller sizes no pooling is used in the encoder except for global pooling, for which we employ soft attention pooling of Li et al. (2015b).

and

> The encoder has two convolutional layers (32 and 64 channels) with batchnorm and ReLU; followed by soft attention pooling (Li et al., 2015b) with 128 channels.

The paper to which they refer is https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05493, but I cannot even understand why they cite it.

Does anybody have any idea as to why they would mention "*128* channels" in a global pooling layer that takes as input 64 channels? Shouldn't it output 64 channels by definition?

Thanks